# Configure Angular2 library with defaultExtension for systemjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, systemjs

Is it possible to setup an npm repo for Angular2 that automatically handles the systemjs config for default extension?

I am building ng2-orm and was curious if this could be automatic when it was npm installed.

my package.json already has a "main" definition, but no default extension. Is there a way to automate this so that when my package gets used the implementer doesn't need to create systemjs.config.js lines for them?

Here is my systemjs.config.js file, see the ng2-orm lines, I had to add those manually.

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
      'ng2-orm': 'npm:ng2-orm'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-orm': {
        main: './dist/js/index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool you want, if you want to automate systemjs.config.js , is the npm module [JSPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspm) . You tell it to install certain modules and it installs those modules and updates the package.json and the systemjs.config.js for you. At least, thats the dream!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out